# How to insert enough spaces to align text to column number using Vim?

Tags: vim, vi

```
  COMP_ID=`      echo $SRC | sed -e 's/.*COMP_ID=//'  -e 's/:.*$//'`
  SRC_TYP=`      echo $SRC | sed -e 's/.*SRC_TYP=//'  -e 's/:.*$//'`
  DOC_TYP=`      echo $SRC | sed -e 's/.*DOC_TYP=//'  -e 's/:.*$//'`
  SRC_ID=`       echo $SRC | sed -e 's/.*SRC_ID=//'      -e 's/:.*$//'`
  ACC=`          echo $SRC | sed -e 's/.*ACC=//'      -e 's/:.*$//'`
  PASS=`         echo $SRC | sed -e 's/.*PASS=//'  -e 's/:.*$//'`
  POP=`          echo $SRC | sed -e 's/.*POP=//'      -e 's/:.*$//'`
  REMOTE_HOST=`  echo $SRC | sed -e 's/.*REMOTE_HOST=//'  -e 's/:.*$//'`
  REMOTE_PATH=`  echo $SRC | sed -e 's/.*REMOTE_PATH=//'  -e 's/:.*$//'`
  ARCHIVE_PATH=` echo $SRC | sed -e 's/.*ARCHIVE_PATH=//' -e 's/:.*$//'`
```

Using vim (or vi) I want to align the sections with `-e 's/:.*$//'` to the same column number. What's the easiest and fastest way to do this? (ignore the ugly `echo ..| sed ..` bits for now)

Comment: Did you consider using a plugin like [Align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=294) or [Tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For alignment, there are three well-known plugins:

- the venerable [Align - Help folks to align text, eqns, declarations, tables, etc](http://www.vim.org/script.php?script_id=294)
- the modern [tabular](https://github.com/godlygeek/tabular)
- the contender [vim-easy-align](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4520)

With the first, your problem can be solved via

```
:%Align -e
```

Comment: Well done. thanks for the those tips. For history's sake, the first two failed to install or operate correctly for me. vim-easy-plugin was the ticket. Did exactly what I want. `vip<enter>-<CTRL-/> -e <enter>` did it for me. My version `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.0 (2006 May 7, compiled Jun 12 2009 07:08:36)
`

Comment: Why are you using such an outdated Vim version?! By updating, you'll get many fixes and new features!

Answer (score 3):

You can do it with no plug-in, like this:

```
:%s#\(.*\)\zs\ze-e#\=repeat(' ',58-len(submatch(1)))
```

Note: This assumes that `-e` is the last of line. But you can capture it otherwise if it is not suitable to your case.

Explanation:

- `%s#\(.*\)` - captures the line before the `-e`.
- `\zs\ze` - starts and stops the match here.
- `-e#` - just before the `-e`.
- Using `\zs` and `\ze` here let us to add our spaces directly before `-e` (otherwise concatenation with `.submatch(x)` would have been possible).
- `\=repeat(' ',58-len(submatch(1)))` - replace this location with a variable number of spaces and where `58` is your aimed column.